# How to download a file to client from server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button, download

I have an MVC project where I'd like the user to be able to download a an excel file with a click of a button. I have the path for the file, and I can't seem to find my answer through google.

I'd like to be able to do this with a simple button I have on my cshtml page:

```
<button>Button 1</button>
```

How can I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the file is not located inside your application folders and not accessible directly from the client you could have a controller action that will stream the file contents to the client. This could be achieved by returning a `FileResult` from your controller action using the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string file = @"c:\someFolder\foo.xlsx";
    string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    return File(file, contentType, Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

and then replace your button with an anchor pointing to this controller action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Button 1", "Download", "SomeController")
```

Alternatively to using an anchor you could also use an html form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit">Button 1</button>
}
```

If the file is located inside some non-accessible from the client folder of your application such as `App_Data` you could use the [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) method to construct the full physical path to this file using a relative path:

```
string file = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.xlsx");
```

Comment: what if the file in different server? let say the server name is "VUP-1" ?
and let say the path is "c:\someFolder\foo.xlsx" --> in server VUP-1

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("UI Text", "function_name", "Contoller_name", new { parameterName = parameter_value },null) </div>
```

Controller:

```
public FileResult download(string filename) {
        string path = "";
        var content_type = "";
        path = Path.Combine("D:\file1", filename);

        if (filename.Contains(".pdf"))
        {
            content_type = "application/pdf";
        }
        return File(path, content_type, filename);
}
```