# Response.TransmitFile does not work in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc 5 application, I save letters files in folder inside folder like (~\Files\Letters) and I save the physical path in database, uploading letters files  to (~\Files\Letters) works fine and saving the physical path works fine, the problem is downloading a letter file to client machine, I have tried using Webclient and Response both don't work and don't give any error, here is the code for downloading a letter file using Response.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void open(int id)
    {

        string path = "";

        path = db.tblLetters.Where(t => t.ID == id).SingleOrDefault().LetterImg;
        string fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"\")+1);
        string p = Server.MapPath("~/Files/LettersImgs/" + fileName);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.TransmitFile(p);
        Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: `public void open(int id)` => this should be `public ActionResult open(int id)` and use `return File(p, "application/octet-stream", fileName)` to return the file (note: you must use `HttpGet` to enable downloading).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using old-style `Response.TransmitFile`, you can use [`FilePathResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx) to return file directly from server's file path. Change return type from `void` to `ActionResult` (or `FileResult`) and use `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]`, and do `return File(...)` to let user download the file like this example below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Open(int id)
{
    string path = "";

    path = db.tblLetters.Where(t => t.ID == id).SingleOrDefault().LetterImg;
    string fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"\")+1);
    string p = Server.MapPath("~/Files/LettersImgs/" + fileName);

    return File(p, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

Related issue: [How to download a file to client from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711271/how-to-download-a-file-to-client-from-server)